# Menus not aligning right

Tags: php, html, css, alignment, right-align

My `register` and `login` buttons won't align to the right. Can you please help me fix this? I will provide any info needed, just ask for it. By the way this is only one part of a bigger menu so it will have extra things in css.

**PHP/ HTML:**

```
<a href="<?php echo URL; ?>login">
    <div class="button first">
        <div class="b left"><!--  --></div>
        <div class="b right"><!--  --></div>
        <div class="b content">Login</div>
    </div>
</a>

<a href="<?php echo URL; ?>register">
    <div class="button first">
        <div class="b left"><!--  --></div>
        <div class="b right"><!--  --></div>
        <div class="floatright">Register</div>
    </div>
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
#page {
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: 1060px;
    min-width: 954px;
    position: relative;
}
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#page {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.m_hmenu {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.m_hmenu .floatright {
    float: right;
}
.m_hmenu .content {
    position: relative;
}
.m_hmenu .content span {
    font-size: 60%;
    margin-left: 6px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1px;
}
.m_hmenu .left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50.004%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: left top;
}
.m_hmenu .right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50.004%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: right top;
}
.m_hmenu .button {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.m_hmenu a:hover .button,
.m_hmenu a:focus .button {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.m_hmenu .cap {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

.m_hmenu .stretch .button {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
}
body {
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-position:center;
    color:#4f4f4f;
    background-image:url("Background.jpg");
}
#page-wrap {
    background-color:transparent;
    margin-right:-5px;
    font-family:Arial;
    color:#4f4f4f;
    margin-left:-5px;
    font-size:13px;
}
a {
    color:#57c11a;text-decoration:none;
}
.m_header {
    padding-bottom:3px;
    border-color:transparent;
    padding-right:4px;
    background-color:transparent;
    padding-left:3px;
    border-width:1px;
    padding-top:3px
}
.m_hmenu {
    height:63px;
}
.m_hmenu .bg.left {
    background-image:url("Menu.png");
}
.m_hmenu .bg.right {
    background-image:url("Menu.png");
}
.m_hmenu .buttons {
padding-right:0px;padding-left:15px;top:2px;
}
.m_hmenu .button {
    background-color:transparent;
    line-height:58px;
    padding-right:15px;
    font-weight:normal;
    height:40px;
    padding-left:15px;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#89e350;
}
.m_hmenu a:hover .button {
    color:#ffffff;
}
.m_hmenu a:focus .button {
    color:#ffffff;
}
.m_hmenu .cap {
    height:40px;
}
```

Thanks Joshua

Comment: can you create a fiddle for better understanding ?

Comment: Do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/s4s3W/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t4tsr/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="login" class="button first">
    <a>Login</a>
</div>

<div id="register" class="button first">
    <a>Register</a>
</div>
```

In CSS :)

```
#login, #register {position:fixed;top:50px}
#login {right:100px}
#register {right:10px}
```